# Knockout returning data from ajax call

Tags: knockout.js

Okay, so I'm fairly new to knockout and I've got a good handle on data-bind.  However, there's a pattern that another programmer put together and I'm wanting to follow it in the same program just a different form.  This is .NET C# MVC5 VMMV.  When I use the code written on the other programmer's page everything returns as it should.  Mine returns but the data binding isn't working.

both are declared in viewmodel
both are called through ajax in model
both return data:

This is in the .cshtml file
HIS CODE: returns profileData ko.observable and returns the label text

```
<div class="btn-group margin-top-md pull-right" data-bind="with: profileData">
<label class="btn btn-success btn-xs active" data-bind="text: opportunityName">
</label>
<label class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-bind="text: status">
</label>
<label class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-bind="text: strengthIsCustom">
</label>
</div>
```

MY CODE: returns getContacts ko.observable, populates getContacts but does not return label test.

```
<div class="btn-group margin-top-md pull-right" data-bind="with: contactData">
<label class="btn btn-success btn-xs active" data-bind="text: TotalPublished">
</label>
<label class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-bind="text: TotalUnpublished">
</label>
<label class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-bind="text: TotalContacts">
</label>
</div>
```

Functions are identical:
MINE:

```
 function getContacts() {
    model.getContacts().then(function (data) {

        contactData({
            TotalUnpublished: data.TotalUnpublished,
            TotalPublished: data.TotalPublished,
            TotalContacts: data.TotalContacts
        });

    });
}
```

HIS:

```
function getProfileData() {
    model.getProfileData().then(function (data) {

        profileData({
            opportunityName: data.OpportunityName,
            status: data.OutcomeStatus,
            strengthIsCustom: data.Strength.IsCustomalysisStarted)
        });

    });
}
```

Does anything stand out here?

Comment: Check the browser console for any errors first. If not Errors, add a console.log(data), to check if you get any data

Comment: There is a typo in 'his' function: trailing 
parenthesis after `data.Strength.IsCustomalysisStarted)`. Have you left some stuff out?

Comment: How is `contactData()` defined compared to `profileData()`?

Comment: getContactData() is a collection of objects.

Comment: getProfileData()  is a single object.

Comment: both are defined as ko.observable().  Is that the problem???  I need an observable array?

Comment: Can you pls create a plunker/jsfiddle/demo link?

Comment: Please post the getProfileData and getContacts functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comments you say that getContacts returns an array of Contact data.  It appears that you need to be using an `observableArray` for the storage of the contact data. assuming that you will want two way data-binding, you also need to loop through the data returned from the server and create a `new ContactData` object to be added to the array.

I have created a jsfiddle demo based on your code around the Contact.  I have just made it work and chances are will need to be adjusted to fit your scenario.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gonefishern/tWB44/6/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn-group margin-top-md pull-right" data-bind="with: contact">
  <label class="btn btn-success btn-xs active" data-bind="text: totalPublished"></label>
  <label class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-bind="text: totalUnpublished"></label>
  <label class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-bind="text: totalContacts"></label>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**
Note: using Q promises library to simulate returning data from server;

```
var model = {
    getContacts: function () {
        return Q.fcall(function () {
            return [{
                TotalUnpublished: 5,
                TotalPublished: 3,
                TotalContacts: 23
            }, {
                TotalUnpublished: 4,
                TotalPublished: 9,
                TotalContacts: 38
            }];
        });
    }
};

function ContactData(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.totalUnpublished = ko.observable(data.TotalUnpublished || 0);
    self.totalPublished = ko.observable(data.TotalPublished || 0);
    self.totalContacts = (data.TotalContacts || 0);
    return self;
}

var contacts = ko.observableArray([]);

function getContacts() {
    model.getContacts().then(function (data) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(data, function (item) {
            contacts.push(new ContactData(data));
        });
    });
}

var vm = {
    getContacts: getContacts,
    contacts: contacts
};
vm.getContacts();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan, just what I was after.